# How to use current stored procedure of database in code smith for create template?

Tags: codesmith

I have a data base and create more stored procedure it,now i want use currently created stored procedures in code smith and create template from it.
What to do?

For example for use from table in code generator write the follow property :

```
<%@ Property Name="SourceTables" Category="Database" Optional="True" Type="SchemaExplorer.TableSchemaCollection" 
Description="The database tables" %>
```

How to Write for stored procedures ????

```
<%@ Property ..... Type="**SchemaExplorer.???**" ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for CodeSmith Tools and there is already a template that does what you want to create stored procedures. It can be found in the Database/StoredProcedures folder. The source can also be found online [here](https://code.google.com/p/codesmith/source/browse/trunk/Templates/Database/StoredProcedures/StoredProcedures.cst).

If you wish to interact with a stored procedure via a property you can do this via the CommandSchema type.

```
<%@ Property Name="SourceCommands" Category="Database" Optional="True" Type="SchemaExplorer.CommandSchemaCollection" 
Description="The database stored procedures" %>
```